# Import from relative folder instead of version installed via pip

Tags: python, pip

I downloaded an open source library that I am making adjustments to, and I am trying to import my local version like `from ... import my_library` but getting `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

When I try just `import my_library` I get the version that I installed via pip

```
% pip install -e /Users/sam/Documents/library
Obtaining file:///Users/sam/Documents/library
ERROR: File "setup.py" not found for legacy project file:///Users/sam/Documents/library

% pip install -e library
ERROR: library is not a valid editable requirement. It should either be a path to a local 
project or a VCS URL (beginning with bzr+http, bzr+https, bzr+ssh, bzr+sftp, bzr+ftp, 
bzr+lp, bzr+file, git+http, git+https, git+ssh, git+git, git+file, hg+file, hg+http, 
hg+https, hg+ssh, hg+static-http, svn+ssh, svn+http, svn+https, svn+svn, svn+file).
```

---

---

i uninstalled the pip module and am trying

```
sys.path.insert(
     0, "/Users/sam/Documents/dev/trading/ccxt/python/ccxt/__init__.py")
ccxt = importlib.import_module("ccxt")  # Equivalent to "import package"
```

but am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sam/Documents/dev/trading/ccxt-scratch/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Exchange import Exchange
  File "/Users/sam/Documents/dev/trading/ccxt-scratch/Exchange.py", line 14, in <module>
    ccxt = importlib.import_module("ccxt")  # Equivalent to "import package"
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ccxt'
```

Comment: Look up `.pth` files in the documentation. You can use one pointed at the library's directory to make its contents importable.

Comment: @martineau How do I just import a local library, without worrying about pip or anything. If I just have a folder locally, how do i import that

Comment: See the subsection that mentions `.pth` files in the [Installing Python Modules (Legacy version)](https://docs.python.org/3/install/index.html?highlight=pth) section in the documentation. Basically you create a text file with the extension `.pth` and put the full path to the local directory containing the library (i.e. `/path/to/the/library`) and save this file in a `site` directory like `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages` or `\PythonXY\Lib\site-packages` depending on your platform.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to install a library from source files that you are modifying is to use pip's [editable mode](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-e).

```
pip install -e /path/to/the/library
```

This way the library will be loaded from the source files ad any changes to it will reflect in your virtual environment (if you are using one).

Comment: do I run `pip install -e /path/to/the/library` after already installing via `pip install library`, and then do I edit the files inside `/path/to/the/library`?

Comment: you should uninstall the library first `pip uninstall library` and then install it in editable mode `pip install -e /path/to/the/library`

Comment: Is library already cloned when I run `pip install -e /path/to/the/library`

Comment: Your solution isn't working, I edited my question, i just need a way to import the local library, I don't need the "best" way, i just need a way that works

Comment: what is the library? the error is saying that your library is not a proper python library (meaning it does not have a setup.py file). Is it only one file? If so just put the file in the same folder you run your program from and just `import library` without pip installing anything

Comment: `ccxt` is the library

Comment: `ccxt` library has a setup.py file. make sure you have properly cloned the repo